# Resolving an ambiguous game state caused by mixing restricted mana

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Anthony activates [Mishra's Workshop](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383015) to add {3} to his mana pool. He casts [Bronze Sable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bronze%20Sable), leaving him with {1} in his mana pool. This mana comes with a restriction that it may only be used to cast artifacts.

Next, Anthony activates [Xenagos, the Reveler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Xenagos%2C%20the%20Reveler) to add {G}{G} to his mana pool. He casts [Elsewhere Flask](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elsewhere%20Flask). This leaves him with one mana in his pool. Elsewhere Flash resolves, and Anthony draws a card.

We arrive at an ambiguous game state. Anthony failed to specify exactly which mana in his pool he was using to cast Elsewhere Flask. Does he have {1} in his pool with a restriction, or {G} in his pool with no restriction? Does the game back up to before it became ambiguous? Does Anthony get to choose? Are any penalties awarded?

Assume that this scenario occurred at Regular AND Competitive REL. Describe the outcome of both if they happen to be different.

Comment: It's only ambiguous if you don't do proper bookkeeping. =)

Comment: @corsiKa I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Rainbolt The comment makes perfect sense. There is no such thing as an "ambiguous game state caused by mixing restricted mana" if every player decision has been properly recorded. Every decision a player can legally make has a defined outcome. Just because players agree on mutually understood, even unspoken or implicit shortcuts does not mean the decisions have not been made.

Comment: I'm not sure how constructive it is to point out that ambiguous games states don't exist if all players follow the rules, when that's obviously not the case here. It's like standing up at the UN and stating that in a perfect world, nobody would be hungry.

Comment: @Rainbolt I think it's just that up until you read through most of the question, it's easy to think you're asking a rules question not a judging question.

Comment: The question *is* a rules question. Do you know what REL stands for?

Comment: Okay, how to rephrase my comment: Your title doesn't match your question. You want to resolve an ambiguous game state caused by a failure to declare game actions. That's the cause. The mixing restricted mana isn't the cause. It's the old "guns don't kill people, people kill people".

Comment: @Rainbolt Indeed, and that's my point: this is a question about rules *enforcement*, not the rules themselves. Yes, I know that there's another set of rules about how to enforce the actual rules. I'm just saying that the beginning of the question (and especially the title) doesn't make it especially clear that you're actually heading toward saying "these people broke the rules, what happens now?"

Comment: @Jefromi Had I known that you think tournament rules are not "actual" rules, then I would have not responded to your comment in the first place. Please feel free to downvote and move on to an "actual" question.

Comment: Of course they're real rules, but they're not the basic rules of the game itself - they're meta rules, or something like that. I'm sorry if "actual" was so poor a choice of words as to cause you to completely disregard my attempt to help clarify your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We will start with the relevant rule:

> **[106.4a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Mana#Comprehensive_Rules)** If a player passes priority (see rule 116) while there is mana in his or her mana pool, that player announces what mana is there. If any mana remains in a player’s mana pool after he or she spends mana to pay a cost, that player announces what mana is still there.

Anthony would get a Warning for Game Play Error - Game Rule Violation for failing to follow the above rule.  (I can't think of a card that having the {1} would be advantageous over the {G}, but board state is irrelevant for this kind of infraction.)

The fix for this type of violation is to attempt to fix the problem by performing the required action if possible, if that isn't back up the game if possible, and if that isn't possible leaving the game state alone. In this case if caught soon enough the problem can be fixed by Anthony deciding what kind of mana he has, otherwise just leave the game where it is.

If Anthony's opponent did not catch the error soon after it was committed they would receive a Warning for Game Play Error - Failure to Maintain Game State.

At a Regular REL both of the Warning should be downgraded to Cautions, since the point at Regular REL is to educate and not punish for most infractions.

Comment: "I can't think of a card that having the {1} would be advantageous over the {G}" - All mountains left and Firespout in hand?

Comment: @HaoYe good point, I'd forgotten about cards like that that care about the color of mana spent

Comment: If the game state is irrelevant to rulings (and I agree with that interpretation), then why does it matter that Anthony gains an advantage for drawing a card? Shouldn't the ruling be totally independent of whether he drew a card or not?

Comment: @Rainbolt You're right, the error occured when they passed priority after putting the spell on the stack, long before they draw the card

Comment: @HaoYe (4 comments up) well, even in that case if you had the {1} you couldn't actually use it to cast Firespout. So the alternatives are being able to cast Firespout dealing 3 damage to flying and non-flying creatures, or not being able to cast it at all, and I think having the choice is strictly better. Of course this is getting off topic, so maybe something to take up in [chat] if anyone wanted to do so.

Answer (score 4):

- Judge (or opponent): "Anthony, what's in your mana pool right now?"
- Anthony: [takes a second] "One green mana."
- Judge (or opponent): "Great!"

There's only a problem here if Anthony misrepresented how much mana he has, or if a state occurs where he made an illegal play. Absolute clarity would be something that would be appreciated from Anthony, however if the game mandated absolute clarity in everything related to the game, a single game could take far too long for a tournament to be efficiently done.

If the mana was misrepresented, assuming no intent, it's a miscommunication made between the two players, which is a Communication Policy Violation at competitive REL, and the miscommunication should be clarified. If an illegal play was made, such as an Elvish Mystic being cast off of the colorless (which was mistaken as G) is a Game Rule Violation at competitive REL, and would be handled based on the remedies perscribed in the IPG. (short version: the game would either be backed up if caught quickly, or left as-is)

Comment: See rule 106.4a - @competitive REL, I would assess GRV for Anthony, and possibly FtMGS for his opponent depending on how fast Anthony moved through his actions.